# How to connect to camera interface on OVM7251-EAAR-AA0A?

Tags: connector, camera, mipi

There's a weird connector on the OVM7251-EAAR-AA0A board from Omnivision:

[image: picture]

It seems to be 40 pin and 2 cm wide, and from the sensor documentation it's supposed to be a 1-lane mipi / lvds interface.

Does anyone know how to connect with this from any computer?

Comment: so you are asking where to find a MIPI/LVDS to USB converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There's a weird connector

Not so weird. My [Connector Identification Utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=board_to_board_conn&o=misc_genderless_b2b_conn_&f=genderless_shielded_b2b_conn&s=Q%20Strip%20QSE%20QSE-EM%20%2B%20QTE%20QTE-EM) identified it as a Samtec [Q strip QTE-020-01-F-D-A](https://www.samtec.com/products/qte).

[image: Samtec connector]

{Image source: [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/samtec-inc/QTE-020-01-F-D-A/3079641)}

Edit: however, knowing the connector tells you nothing of the port (the protocol interface).

Comment: @SamGibson: your indefatigable work is priceless. Thank you,